# Set start number on 7490 circuit

Tags: flipflop, counter

Is it possible to make the 7490 in BCD encoded output mode (divide by 10) have a "start" state and limit its count to a certain number? What I am looking for is a way to make the 7490 start at 1 (0001) and then have it count up to 5 (0101) then back again at 1.

Comment: Do you care if you have to add some logic?

Comment: If extra logic is not a problem do you really need to use a 7490?

Comment: I don't really care as long as its just "some" logic, in fact as an alternative I thought on using a decimal counter and a dec-to-bcd encoder, im open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you are only counting from 1 to 5, there is no need to specify a BCD counter.

Second, and more importantly, don't use a 7490 for almost anything, especially an application in which you are going to operate on the outputs. Instead, go to something like a 74161 or a 74191. These have a synchronous clock and either a synchronous or asynchronous load, which will take a good deal of the potential heartache out of decoding and feeding back outputs.

Third, you need to provide a POR, Power On Reset, which will force the counter to the desired state when power is applied. This can be as simple as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0m5Ak.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the inverter should almost certainly be a Schmitt Trigger, with the 7414 as the standard part.

If you do go to a better counter, you will find a conflict between your POR and a feedback reset. POR is easier with an asynchronous load, but feedback loads will be far better served with a synchronous load.

Comment: I have managed to get past the first issue by settling down with a divide by 6 mode, so the 1-5 thing doesnt matter much now, and your power-on-reset circuit works well except for two things: 1. since the Q2 and Q4 outputs have to be connected to RST1 and RST2 respectively and the POR has to be connected to RST1, the POR will be activated prematurely at Q4 and end the count, and 2. the POR signal won't work through a diode (not even a 4148). I guess I will just settle for a 4017 a pair of 7404s and a 74147.

Comment: I also noticed that when the POR circuit is connected, the count will trigger (i.e. go from 0-1, 1-2, 2-3, etc.) when the clock goes HIGH and also when it goes LOW, rather than only "counting" when it goes to LOW (as it does when either RST or both are held LOW). Also I can't just connect 1 RST and hold the other LOW as it won't trigger the reset on startup.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fckjZv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this way, you only have to add a 7400 and a 7486 package. The 7490 is used in its bi-quinary mode, where it naturally counts from binary 000 to 100. The gates shown essentially "add 1" to this.